# Why does running this query in node.js block the process from exiting?

Tags: node.js

Why does running queries using the [pg module](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) block the process from terminating?

This piece of code is taken straight from the github page's readme. Executing this node.js script in terminal performs the sql query but does not return to the bash prompt right away. It probably takes about 20 seconds to exit.

```js
var pg = require('pg'); 
var conString = "tcp://postgres:1234@localhost/postgres";

//error handling omitted
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
  client.query("SELECT NOW() as when", function(err, result) {
    console.log("Row count: %d",result.rows.length);  // 1
    console.log("Current year: %d", result.rows[0].when.getYear());
  });
});
```

Comment: Does adding a `pg.end` call help?

Comment: Ah yes! Post that as an answer and I'll mark it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call `pg.end`.